# Interfaces and properties

Tags: delphi, interface, properties

Is it possible to declare a property in an interface without declaring the get- and set-methods for it? Something like:

```
IValue = interface
  property value: double;
end;
```

I want to state that the implementor should have a property called value, returning a double, but I really don't care if it returns a private field or the result from a function.

If it is possible, is it possible to declare it read/write or read-only?

Comment: This is that makes me hate delphi.. :D.

Comment: when there is so many other reasons to pick from? Actually, I liked Delphi quite much, but it's a closed chapter for me now.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan It's' probably the worst thing I don't like about Delphi (being a Delphi lover since Turbo Pascal 2)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No.  Interfaces are implemented as function tables (basically a simple virtual method table) and the compiler needs to know there's a function to map the property onto.  You can declare a property on an interface, but it has to have functions as getter/setter values, not fields.  You can make it read-only or write-only, though.

Answer (score 8):

When working with properties in an interface, think of the property as a shortcut to the reader/writer.  Only one is required to satisfy the shortcut...otherwise it doesn't point to anything.

Comment: Yep.  In fact, the property declaration is purely there for your convenience.  If you create an interface with a property on it, and put it on a class that implements the functions but doesn't declare the property, that class will compile just fine.